# $\lim_{x\to 0} \log (\frac{1}{\epsilon x^2})^{x^{c}}=0?$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> How to get the limit about
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0} \log \left[\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon x^2}\right)^{x^{c}}\right]=0?$$
>   where $\epsilon$ is enough small.

My goal is to let the limit be zero. Can I make the limit very small by making c very large

Comment: $\log[(1/\varepsilon x^2)^{x^\varepsilon}]$ or $[\log[(1/\varepsilon x^2)]^{x^\varepsilon}$

Comment: @TitoEliatron the first one

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \log \left[\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon x^2}\right)^{x^{c}}\right]= 
\lim_{x\to 0} \log \bigg[\big(\sqrt{\epsilon} x\big)^{-2x^{c}}\bigg]= -2 \lim_{x\to 0} x^c\log(\sqrt\varepsilon x)$

Comment: @TitoEliatron $0 (-\infty)$?

Comment: Is the exponent $x^c$ or $x^{\varepsilon}$? It's hard to see.

Comment: @bjorn93 it is c.

Comment: @BobOakley What are the restrictions for $c$? Any real number?

Comment: @bjorn93 yes, any real number. But $c$ can be large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following fact:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{\beta}\log x=0 $$
for any $\beta >0$. Using standard properties of the logarithm $\left(\log(x^a)=a\log(x)\right)$, the expression can be rewritten as
$$\log\left(\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon x^2}\right)^{x^c}\right)=-x^c\log\left(\varepsilon x^2\right)=-2x^c\log(\sqrt{\varepsilon}x) $$
Using the fact above, it follows that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(-2x^c\log(\sqrt{\varepsilon}x)\right)=0 $$
for any $c>0$ and any $\varepsilon>0$. Also note that we can only talk about the one-sided limit as $x\to 0^+$ if we want to stay in real numbers. $x^c$ cannot be generally defined as a real number for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that:
$$\ln \bigg{(}\frac{1}{\epsilon x^{2}}\bigg{)}^{x^{\epsilon}} = -x^{\epsilon}\ln \epsilon x^{2} = -2x^{\epsilon}\ln \epsilon - 2x^{\epsilon}\ln x$$
For a given fixed $\epsilon > 0$, the first limit is trivially zero. What about the second one?

Comment: That is $0 (-\infty)$. But I feel like $x^c\to 0$ is faster.

Comment: Yes. You can see that by noting that, if we define $x' = 1/x$ then $x \to 0^{+}$ implies $x' \to +\infty$. Then, $ln(x) = -ln(x')$ and you can use L'Hospital. The case $x' = -1/x$ for $x \to 0^{-}$ is analogous.